# Multivariate Analysis

Tags: calculus, matrices, vectors

I have the following exercise:

Given: $f(x)= < x,w>$ show that $\nabla f(x)=w$ and

given $f(x)=\|Bx-c\|^2_2$ show that $\nabla f(x)=2B^T(Bx-c)$,
where $f:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, w \in \mathbb{R}^d, B=(b_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times d}$

How exactly do I solve this type of exercise? Usually when I have the gradient vector $\nabla$ I just compute the partial derivaties, make a system in which I make all of them equal to 0, find the solutions (which are the critical points) and then compute the Hessian matrix by replacing these points in the partial derivatives. But here I have vectors and matrices instead of "normal" variables.

How shall I proceed in this case?

Comment: Do you know what is the derivative/gradient/differential of a linear function? Ditto for bilinear?

Comment: No. The only details I have are the ones I wrote in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the first case:
$$f(x)=x_1w_1+\cdots x_nw_n.$$
The second case also can be written using coordinates but is *much* worse.

Comment: I think that $x$ is just a variable, not a vector. So I have $f(x)=x*(w_1+...+w_n)$. But how do I differentiate $w$? Or do I need to use another method than the one I explained in the question?

Comment: The $\langle,\rangle$ is the scalar product of *vectors*. And the variable (vector) is $x$, the $w$ is constant.

Comment: Ok, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=w$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}=x$, right? But how do I show that the gradient vector is $w$? If I just make a system with both of them, then they are 0 and that doesn't help me very much.

Comment: @user1956190, *forgot* equaling things to 0. The objective is calculating the gradient.

Comment: @user1956190, what is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}$?

Comment: Is it $w_i$? And then the gradient vector is composed of out $w_i$, where $i \in \{1,...,n\}$ which is the $w$ vector? Is that it? The entire solution?

Comment: @user1956190, right.

Comment: Wow. It was so much easier than I expected. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: One more question, though: since I have $f(x)$ shouldn't I compute the derivatives at point $x$? Then, wouldn't the derivatives be $w_i*x$?

Comment: @user1956190, what is your definition of derivatives?

Comment: Derivatives are functions for which the limit at a certain point exists.

Comment: @user1956190, *definitely*, aren't.